# how to pass arraylist as parameter to another screen

Tags: android

how to pass arraylist as parameter to another activity in my condition im not using listview and checkif arraylist contain single element then pass that arrraylist as parameter toanother screen see thisline  Category_name.get(position).toString());   how i remove position?? how to passs arraylist parameter toanother activity

```
      static ArrayList<Long> Menu_ID = new ArrayList<Long>();
    static ArrayList<String> Category_name = new ArrayList<String>();



            JSONArray school = json2.getJSONArray("data");

    for (int i = 0; i < school.length(); i++) {

         JSONObject object = school.getJSONObject(i);



    Category_ID.add((long) i);


   Menu_ID.add(Long.parseLong(object.getString("menu_id")));

       Category_name.add(object.getString("menu_title"));

            }


                     Intent iMenuList = new Intent(MenuGroup.this, thirdstep.class);
                    menuidvalue="";

                 menuidvalue =( Menu_ID.get(position)).toString();



                iMenuList.putExtra("Menu_ID",menuidvalue);
                iMenuList.putExtra("menu_group",   
                                  Category_name.get(position).toString());
                                    startActivity(iMenuList);
```

Comment: Use some Full Stops in question. I can't really understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass an arraylist from one activity to another,  try the following code:

```
Intent ide = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
ide.putStringArrayListExtra("tag_name", YourArrayList);
ide.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(ide);
```

If it is integer arraylist, use:

```
ide.putIntegerArrayListExtra("tag_name", YourArrayList);
```

instead of

```
ide.putStringArrayListExtra("tag_name", YourArrayList);
```

Comment: supose if in my arraylist  has string"hello" when pass to another activity is show string in textview???

Comment: If my answer helped you to solve the OP, then you can accept it:)

Comment: In another activity, you use position and get your necessary string from that position of arraylist and then populate it to textview..

Comment: @user2867267 int pos = arraylist.indexOf("string you need"); then, textview.setText(arraylist.get(pos));

Answer (score 0):

Trying to transfer a lot of data between activities is a sign that you're going wrong way.
Use some external data source like DB or content providers and transfer data descriptors (id of a list, not a list of ids).